# Async calls using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

We are making multiple HTTP requests using Angular:

```
$scope.GetTest1 = function () {
    $http.get("/test/GetTest1/").success(function (response) {
        $scope.res = response.aaData;
    });
} 

$scope.GetTest2 = function () {
    $http.get("/test/GetTest2/").success(function (response) { 
        $scope.res = response.aaData; 
    });
}

$scope.GetTest3 = function () {
    $http.get("/test/GetTest3/").success(function (response) { 
        $scope.res = response.aaData; 
    });
}

// This is called from an onclick of a button
$scope.LoadAll = function () {
    $scope.GetTest1();
    $scope.GetTest2();
    $scope.GetTest3();
}
```

We assumed that these were all called async, however, we have `log4net` enabled and we log the datetime when the 'gets' are received, and the times for all 3 are:

19:05:26

19:05:27

19:05:28

This was an unexpected surprise as we assumed the time would all be within 1 second. ie async.

Not sure if we're missing something,

Sorry,  question is,  how do we make these async calls?

Comment: @lin Sorry,  just updated,   basically,  how do we make these async?

Comment: javascript is non-blocking and will not wait for a function to return.  You need a promise chain for something like this.

Comment: Have you watched the requests in your browser's Network tab? Are you sure that your _server_ isn't queuing the requests and handling them one at a time?

Comment: @JLRishe we're not expecting them to all complete with a second, however, we we're expecting the api to be hit 3 times pretty much within a second, however its not

Comment: @Simon I revised my question.

Comment: @JLRishe looking at the network tab, they do seem to be queuing, however, shouldnt the browser handle up to 6 http requests at a time?

Comment: I did not get the problem right now. All requests are "async" in your example. So the question is answered in itself.

Comment: @Simon Are the requests being _sent_ one after the other, or are the bars overlapping?

Comment: @JLRishe column is starttime, and they are overlapped, however, the bars increase in size for each call with a larger stalled and waiting time.

Comment: @Simon Well, then it sounds like the server is queuing them. What kind of server is it? Do you know if it can serve up simultaneous requests?

Comment: @JLRishe  its a windows server 2008, site runs through IIS 7 ( its a .net API ) I have no reason to believe that it cant serve up simultaneous requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the reason of that perhaps is on the server side. I had almost the same result when server could serve only one request from one client. If response from server fulfils your `$http` requests in one second then that could be a problem. Please check your network statistics and if you see that they were called simultaneously but were served not immediately then it's server side problem.

You can easily track this on browser's devtools' timeline

Comment: Hi, just to confirm, your saying thats it possible that the server could only serve one http request at a time per client?

Comment: Looks like servers' pool is limited to 1 request. Hope these points will help you.

Comment: Hi, yes,   finally resolved - the issue was actually due to the .net framework queuing the process per session... [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)] added to each controller resolved the issue, and now all requests are within ms of each other...